# Concatenate several files with a common header

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have several text files, and each file's content is like

```
attribute1,attribute2,...
1,2,...
```

The first lines which describe the names of the columns are the same in all the files.

I want to concatenate the second lines of the files,  add a new column with filename for each line for which file it comes from, and put one of the first lines as the first line in the new file. For example, the desired new file looks like:

```
file,attribute1,attribute2,...
file1,1,2,...
file2,11,12,...
file3,21,22,...
```

How should I do that?

Comment: So each file has just two lines ?

Comment: yes. @don_crissti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the file name, with `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NR==1{print "file", $0};FNR==2{print FILENAME, $0}' file1 file2 ... fileN >outfile
```

which prints the updated header if it's the first line of input (`NR==1`) or (`||`) if it's the second line of each file(`FNR==2`) it prints the `FILENAME` and the line (`$0`).

---

Initial answer before your edit.
You could do that with `sed`:

```
sed -n '1p;n;p' file1 file2 ... fileN >outfile
```

the `-n` suppresses printing, `1p` prints the first line and then for each (odd) line it empties the pattern space and reads in the `n`ext line (the even lines that is) and `p`rints it.

Comment: thanks. how do you do the same with awk?

Comment: I forgot that I would like to add a new column, which consists of the filename for each line. See my update.

Comment: I realized that after I commented. this is a bit more clear: `'NR==1 || FNR==2'`

Comment: @tim, update your question with the new requirements. Don't bury them in comments.

Comment: @glenn: exactly.

Comment: Thanks. @don. Is `FILENAME` a variable in awk to keep track of the file currently being processed? I think I still simplified my problem a little too much. In my case the input text files have the same name but under different directories, what I hope is to use their parent directories as the first column.  Should I copy the text files to be under a  new directory and rename the files to be their parent directories' names, before applying your awk command?

Comment: Thanks. After copying and renaming the input text files, I realize some new issues: (1) the input text files are actually `.gz` compressed files, so can  awk work with `.gz` compressed text files? (2) the names of the input text files are like `file1.csv.gz`, is it possible to extract `file1` from the filename to add to the new column?

Comment: @Tim - I think I better delete my answer here until you make up your mind... really... You _just realized_ those files are `gz` compressed files ? No, awk won't work with compressed files, you could pass the args as `<(gzip -dc file1.csv.gz)` etc but then you no longer get the file name (you'll get `/proc/self/fd/...`)

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to decompress the files first. Your reply is good enough for solving my simplified questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
{   printf file,; head -n1 <file
    grep -n '' ./file* /dev/null|
    sed -ne'/^[^:]*:2:/s/:.:/,/p'
}   >./new_file
```

`grep` will get your filenames at the head of each line, and can assist in selecting by line -`n`umber as well. this will probably not work very well, though, if you've got colons in your filenames.

Comment: Mike, I think you could ditch the `/dev/null` in this case as we're talking about at least two files. Also, I think this post could be updated (with `zgrep`) per the latest OP requirements (see comments under my post) and would in fact be much better for what OP actually wants to do as it would work with `gz` files.

Comment: @don_crissti - but i like the `/dev/null` - it's reassuring, habitual. and i just prefer to cover those kinds of bases, and i feel like thinking about them keeps me sharp.

Answer (score 1):

With `tail`

```
cat file1.txt && tail -q -n +2 file2.txt file3.txt ..
```